# access 2007 locked

Tags: c#, .net, ms-access, ms-access-2007

I'm connecting the access 2007 database from 5 different machines. (C#.Net)

I'm having this error message:

```
The database has been placed in a state by user 'Admin' on machine XXXXX that prevents it from being opened or locked
```

Comment: I m trying to copy access file for each client. Thanks for reply..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This means that someone is editing one of the database objects, like adding a field to a table or creating a new query or similar, in short they have something in the database open in editing mode.

Answer (score 0):

Access databases should be split into front-end for forms, reports, code etc, and back-end for tables.

The back-end should be placed in a directory with a minimum of read and write permissions, otherwise the lock file (ldb) can get locked up.

Each user should have a copy of the front-end.

Comment: C#.NET is in the original question, so not exactly relevant.

Comment: I think it is, because clearly someone is doing something in Access at the same time as C#Net is happening.